# Is API_Key necessary and where it is required for using Google Map API JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to work with google map using below script reference.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Even if i am not using api key obtained from Google service, this works for me.
When i search over web mostly the startup point is to create api key.
It may be simple, but still it need to be cleared whether it is necessary or not? also where it is required.

Answer (score 1):

When [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/) was [first released](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2010/03/introducing-new-google-geocoding-web.html), it does not require a key. You should note that at that time, usage of Google Maps API was completely free of cost. Since then, high usage has become chargeable, and hence Google has started recommending to use a key. Like V2, you can only use it for applications which are free and publicly accessible. If it's for a commercial product, you'll need the Google Maps API Premier.

The OpenLayers Library works by calling the Google Maps API v3 in the background.

So you will find old tutorials, forum posts and answers which say that a key is not required, but I always use a key, as it just takes a minute or so to get the key, and there are no other downsides.

I'll strongly recommend that you use the Google Maps Layer with a Key.

While you will find that Google Maps works without a key, Every official Documentation and sample I can currently access, says that you need to use a Key.

The [Getting Started page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) says:
All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key. Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to purchase additional quota.

NOTE: You do need to have a [Google Maps API Premier key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/?csw=1) if it is for commercial use. See the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial) on the subject.

Let me know if you face any further query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are correct it works for now. Sooner or later Google willmake it fail and you'll have to create and add a valid API Key.

Comment: There are different limits now with free vs paid keys in some API's - perhaps with NO key, the limit is even more restrictive?